# C++ compilation error on Mac OSX: gsl library not found

Tags: c++, gsl

I'm new to C++ programming. This seems a common error but I can't seem to solve: I'm trying to use the `gsl` library, with no luck: using `/usr/bin/g++` to compile, for instance, the following minimal (supposed to be) working example (available [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2020/01/26/getting-started-gsl-gnu-scientific-library-windows-macos-linux/#gsl_usage_example)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

int main() {
    cout << "This is a test" << endl;

    double A_data[] = {
        0.57092943, 0.00313503, 0.88069151, 0.39626474,
        0.33336008, 0.01876333, 0.12228647, 0.40085702,
        0.55534451, 0.54090141, 0.85848041, 0.62154911,
        0.64111484, 0.8892682 , 0.58922332, 0.32858322
    };
 
    double b_data[] = {
        1.5426693 , 0.74961678, 2.21431998, 2.14989419
    };

    // Print the values of A and b using GSL print functions
     std::cout << "A = \n";
     gsl_matrix_fprintf (stdout, &A.matrix, "%lf");

    return 0;
}
```

yields:

`fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_linalg.h' file not found`

**My question is: how to declare correctly the path to the gsl library (on MacOSX)?**

What I've already tried, with no success (or without identifying what I did wrong)

- Redefining the paths as recommended [here](https://github.com/fgvieira/ngsDist/issues/3#issuecomment-258472801)
- Compiling using:`g++` for a start, then using`` g++ -std=c++11 path/to/script.cpp `pkg-config --libs gsl` ``  (the command used in the scripts I'm trying to run) and `g++ -Wall -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include -c path/to/script.cpp` (as suggested [here](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/10/12/using-the-gnu-scientific-library-on-a-mac/)).

Some additional information that may be useful:

- I'm on a Mac, OSX Monterey 12.1, with M1 chip
- I'm using VS code, but I also tried in Xcode, with no success
- I installed the gsl library using homebrew (so the library was placed at the `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1` address instead of `/usr/local/include/gsl`).
- I used `brew update-reset` to go back to the original settings in case I had done a mistake

Comment: Does the path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7/include/gsl/` exist? If not you might have to remove the path from the filename in the #include.

Comment: Can you confirm that /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1/include/gsl/gsl_linalg.h exists? If not please tell us where gsl_linalg.h lives

Comment: Yes, both of these paths exist.

Comment: Now that I can comment I'll do here... 1) Try to execute: pkg-config --cflags glib and see what you get. 2) change #include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h> to #include "gsl/gsl_linalg.h"

Comment: Thanks! For 1) I get "command not found", should I install pkg-config? What would that be useful for? And with 2) the error persists.

Comment: 1) you don't need pkg-config but it's very convenient
2) yes... the path should be #include "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/2.7/include/gsl/gsl_linalg.h"
3) seems that this question is more about to how to compile a C++ program than anything related with GSL
4) Bear in mid that GSL is written in C and you're using C++. It's easy to mix them if you know how to do it but I think you should use a C++ wrapper for GSL. Good luck!!!

Comment: I'm very sorry that this post has been closed. I have the exact same problem and I'm about to cry.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that pkg-config uses a backticks, **`**, not **'**

An you say "...I installed the gsl library using homebrew (so the library was placed at the /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/**2.7.1**" but you're using "g++ -Wall -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gsl/**2.7**/include -c path/to/script.cpp"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 

I edited my question to correct the version of gsl in the address (resulting from a very recent update) and to correct the backticks, which I had wrongfully edited to avoid the command to break due to the code format being triggered (sorry for the confusion).

As these mistakes regard how I asked the question, and they are not present in my code, the error persists.